# php refering to a variable from string

Tags: php, string, variables

I'm trying to refer to a variable that's made up from a string, so say `$type = "pistol"`, then:

```
if ($number > $($type. "s_XP"))
```

would be

```
if ($number > $pistols_XP)
```

Obviously the top one isnt correct syntax, because I don't know how it should be written. 
Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
if ($number > ${$type . "s_XP"})
```

However, you should be storing this data in an object instead (or perhaps an array):

```
$pistol = new Weapon(50);
$nuke = new Weapon(9001);

$type = $pistol;

if($number > $type->XP)
```

Comment: Also: `$var = $type . "s_XP"; if( $number > $$var ) ...`

Comment: $type is actually pulled from a database as $rs[type], just simplified it for the question. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Close.

```
if ($number > ${$type."s_XP"})
```

But you should be using arrays instead.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax:

```
if ($number > $data["pistol"]["xp"])
```

learn to use *arrays*